# How to choose auxiliary equations in Charpit's method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In Charpit's method to solve non linear partial differential equations,from the five auxiliary equations I get,which two do I choose to find the values of p and q?

Comment: There is no such fancy rule but you have to choose according to your convenience (depending upon problems).

Comment: I mean,can we choose the auxiliary equations containing dx and dy?Or are we only supposed to use auxiliary equations containing dp,dq and dz?